# Time changes when rebooting kubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, kubuntu, time

I have installed a dual boot system with windows 7 and kubuntu but every time i reboot my system; time changes in my kubuntu. Initially frequency of time changing was less but now its changing every time i reboot. Rebooting not only changes the time in kubuntu but also changes time in windows also.

I have seen similar problem in this same SE [Kubuntu and Windows 7 dual boot, clock time changes automatically](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35743/kubuntu-and-windows-7-dual-boot-clock-time-changes-automatically) , i tried to use the solution given there.

```
sudo kate /etc/default/rcS
```

but my UTC value is already a no

```
# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=no
```

Can anyone give a solution for this problem. Advance thanks for the help

Comment: Same problem here with Kubuntu 13.04 and Windows XP dual boot. It dives me crazy. And not only time in Kubuntu rolls back to UTC, my Windows XP time roll backs too!

Answer (score 0):

Now the settings are managed by the `/etc/adjtime`. Just edit the file and be sure that the last line says LOCAL:

```
-3618.710110 1377987830 0.000000
1377987830
LOCAL
```